# Looping through string keeping only digits and decimal points

Tags: c#

After reading answers to similar questions I came up with the following approach to my problem of testing the contents of a text box for a number.

My question now is: Is my solution as simple as it can be?

```
 internal static string testStringForNumber(string v)
    {
        // example: string strToTest = Data.CommonMethods.testStringForNumber(this.amountTextBox.Text.Trim());
        string returnValue = "";
        string chr = "";
        int nLen = v.Length;
        int i = 0; // this is my counter
        while (i < nLen)
        {
            chr = v.Substring(i, 1);
            switch (chr)
            {
                case ".":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "0":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "9":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "8":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "7":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "6":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
                case "1":
                    returnValue = returnValue + chr;
                    break;
            }

            i = i + 1;
        }


        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: `string` is an enumerable of `char`, so instead of doing the costly substring operation, you can just do `foreach (char c in v)`. Also, use `StringBuilder` if you are appending many strings or chars together, it will be more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Your title says you want to keep the characters which fulfill a certain criteria, but the name of the method in your snippet seems to indicate you just want to check if a string is a number or not. So which is it?

Comment: You should also use `char.IsDigit(chr)` instead of multiple case constructs.

Comment: instead use regex.... that to me is way simplier

Comment: The name of the method is `testStringForNumber`, yet it doesn't really test anything. Instead it just mangles the input string to remove any non-numeric characters. I don't really understand how this is useful. For example, is the output `47`, from the input `b4r7` appropriate?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I've seen assignments like this before, they are either schoolwork or simple online coding tests used by employers. Small coding questions which do not really demonstrate skill but quickly filters out those without a clue.

Comment: I'm sure you are all very brilliant. However, your answers have demonstrated that my original approach is simpler, clearer, and will run just as fast if not faster.

Answer (score 2):

It is not, I'll give a one-liner here, but I'd recommend `StringBuilder` for code maintainance.

```
public string NumbersAndDecimalPoints(string input)
{
  return new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(t => char.IsDigit(t) || t == '.').ToArray());
}
```

If a string is what you want. Else you can parse it to a number as well.

```
return decimal.Parse(NumbersAndDecimalsPoints(v));
```

If on the other hand the task is finding out if the string is a valid number, I'd either go with @Steve and use `Any()` or just try to parse it.

Using `Any()` (which won't catch multiple separators):

```
var isNumber = !input.ToCharArray().Any(c => "1234567890.".IndexOf(c) < 0);
```

Using `TryParse()` (really the best method):

```
var number = 0m;
var isNumber = decimal.TryParse(input, out number); // is number true = is valid number
```

Comment: Nice, but could be faster using Any

Comment: @Steve Please elaborate, in how could `Any()` improve it?

Comment: Uhm I see an incoherence between title and question. If title is right then your answer is correct. But the question talks about only checking if there are valid numbers. In that case using _input.ToCharArray().Any(c => "1234567890.".IndexOf(c) < 0)_ should be faster than using Where and checking each char with IsDigit

Comment: @Steve That is very true. I didn't see the question like that, but I'll add it as an edit as well.

Comment: @Steve neither this code nor yours will really help for that matter ; checking if a string is only made of digits or decimal separator isn't enough. Currently nothing prevent the input to have more than one decimal separator. A solution based on regex or using `someNumericType.TryParse` seems better IMO.

Comment: Again correct. The multiple decimal point problem escaped me, then better use TryParse than Regex

Comment: @Sehnsucht That is very true, added it to my answer, although I believe the actually question comes from a simple coding assignment thinga-magig and it is actually about filtering strings and not something useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regex instead personally.

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(strToTest,@"[^\d.]","");
```

Of course, I don't know WHY you would do this. Something like "Test 23. Test 42." Will return the string `23.42.`

Comment: grrrr you beat me to it ;-)